# Ubuntu shell script for starting multiple Postgres servers

Tags: 20.04, bash, scripts, postgresql

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and I'm tying to write a .sh script that starts up 2 postgres servers. I disabled pw requirement for sudo in /etc/sudoers

here is my script so far and it's probably incorrect. `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su postgres
postgres -D /usr/local/mydb1 -p <port no.> &
postgres -D /usr/local/mydb2/data -p <diff port no.> &
```

The outcome I get after running the script:

```
shafin@shafin-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ ./test.sh
postgres@shafin-VirtualBox:/home/shafin/Desktop$
```

Looks like it's only executing the first line of the script.

can anyone please help?

Thanks,
Shafin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @waltinator and @steeldriver for your feedbacks.

I was able to work out a solution using both of your suggestions. Here's my updated script in case anyone is looking to do something similar:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin//postgres -D /usr/local/mydb1 -p 8432 &
sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin//postgres -D /usr/local/mydb2/data -p 6432 &
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `sudo su postgres` command starts a new shell, under the "`postgres`" userid. This new shell doesn't read from the script file, so it never sees the rest of the file.

A better way (that works) is to remove the `sudo su postgres` command, and preface the remaining two lines with `sudo -u postgres`. Read `man sudo sudoers`.

Comment: So I tried this line: `sudo -u postgres -D /usr/local/capdb -p 8432 &`

and the response i get is this:

`usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user]
            [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] file ...`

Comment: Looks like its looking for more arguments? Not sure what else I'm supposed to pass in here

Comment: @ShafinM `sudo -u postgres postgres -D /usr/local/capdb -p 8432 &` - the first `postgres` is the user argument to the `sudo -u` option; the second `postgres` is the command

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: @steeldriver already tried that command, bash replies with a unknown command 'postgres' . I know for sure Postgres is set up correctly on this machine because I'm able to start the servers one by one

Comment: @ShafinM where is it located though? remember `sudo` uses its own `secure_path` - which may be different from your interactive shell's `PATH`. If in doubt, use the absolute path ex. `sudo -u postgres /path/to/postgres <other args>`